# If condition expression not working

Tags: python, if-statement

I have two lists with the following values

```
List1=['6', '9', '16', '19', '0', '3', '6', '0', '6', '12', '18']

List2=['9', '16', '19', '24', '3', '6', '19', '6', '12', '18', '24']
```

Below is loop from my python code, where the if condition does not
work when idk is 60, time=60/60=1k

In this case it should go inside the if condition when list1k has '0' and list 2 has '3'. However the `if` condition does not work. I have also tried using the following expression:

```
if ((time >=List1[i]) and (time <=List2[i])):
```

This is the code:

```
for id in range(60,63):
    time = id/ 60
    for i in range(0, len(List1) - 1):
    if (((time >List1[i])or(time==List1[i])) and ((time <List2[i])or(time==List2[i]))):
        print "inside IF"
```

Comment: Also might be worth doing `for L1, L2 in zip(List1, List2):`

Comment: @shuttle87: the OP states that they tried that too.

Comment: `id/ 60` returns `1` for all values of your range.

Comment: @elyon: glad you found multiple answers helpful. Do take into account you can mark just *one* as accepted, usually you'd pick the one that helped you the *most*. The choice is entirely yours, but stick to just one. :-) See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are comparing float value and string values. time is converted to float and List1 and List2 have string values. To overcome this error, declare List1 and List2 to be integers:

```
List1=[6, 9, 16, 19, 0, 3, 6, 0, 6, 12, 18]                                       
List2=[9, 16, 19, 24, 3, 6, 19, 6, 12, 18, 24]
```

Also, I see indentation error in your if statement following the second for loop. The code should be:

```
for id in range(60,63):
    time = id/ 60
    for i in range(0, len(List1) - 1):
        if ((time >=List1[i]) and (time <=List2[i])):
            print("inside IF")
```

It should work with these changes.

Consider the below modifications to your code though not necessary.

With above code, time will be of data type float in Python 3.3(Dont know about lower versions).
Explicitly convert it to integer type using the below statment:

```
time=int(id/60)
```

Comment: The OP is **not** comparing float values, the division will produce integers instead. This is Python *2*, not 3 (see the `print` statement) and if it was Python 3, the code would have thrown an exception (`TypeError: unorderable types: float() > str()`)

Comment: Yes you are right. I said it in my answer that I am using Python 3.3 and Python 2.

Comment: The distinction is important and absolutely relevant to the problem (e.g. you are not answering why the OP was seeing the problem in the first place, not correctly). The OP has tried to mark *all* answers as helpful, yours last, so now we have a situation where it looks as if yours was the most helpful. But it is also *incomplete* at best.

Answer (score 8):

You are comparing strings and integers. Numbers are always sorted before strings, so `time` is always going to be lower than both `List1[i]` and `List2[i]`.

Use *integers* in your lists instead:

```
List1 = [6, 9, 16, 19, 0, 3, 6, 0, 6, 12, 18]
List2 = [9, 16, 19, 24, 3, 6, 19, 6, 12, 18, 24]
```

Python 2 tries to make everything orderable, which is why it is legal to compare strings and integers, but it also means you can make mistakes like these. Python 3 removed this goal and trying to compare strings to integers like this raises an error instead.

Note that you are also using *integer division* because both operands to the `/` division operator are integers. You may want to use floating point division instead:

```
time = id / 60.0
```

although I am not entirely certain what output you were expecting from the division. With integer division the outcome of `60 / 60`, `61 / 60` and `62 / 60` is always going to be `1`.

Your `if` expression can be simplified with comparison chaining:

```
if List1[i] <= time <= List2[i]:
```

You can use the `zip()` function to pair up values from the two lists:

```
for id in range(60, 63):
    time = id / 60.0
    for lower, higher in zip(List1, List2):
        if lower <= time <= higher:
            print 'inside if with lower={}, higher={}, time={}'.format(lower, higher, time)
```

This outputs:

```
>>> List1 = [6, 9, 16, 19, 0, 3, 6, 0, 6, 12, 18]
>>> List2 = [9, 16, 19, 24, 3, 6, 19, 6, 12, 18, 24]
>>> for id in range(60, 63):
...     time = id / 60.0
...     for lower, higher in zip(List1, List2):
...         if lower <= time <= higher:
...             print 'inside if with lower={}, higher={}, time={}'.format(lower, higher, time)
... 
inside if with lower=0, higher=3, time=1.0
inside if with lower=0, higher=6, time=1.0
inside if with lower=0, higher=3, time=1.01666666667
inside if with lower=0, higher=6, time=1.01666666667
inside if with lower=0, higher=3, time=1.03333333333
inside if with lower=0, higher=6, time=1.03333333333
```

Comment: A design mistake that was fixed with Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python2
>>> int < str
True
```

This is because you're comparing integers and strings, see [Built-in Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type
>   names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison
>   are ordered by their address
>   This was "fixed" in Python3:

This was "fixed" in Python3:

```
python3
>>> int < str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: type() < type()
```